# WKWebView content change event

Tags: macos, xamarin, wkwebview

I am developing an app that uses WKWebView on MacOS with Xamarin.Mac framework. My goal is to analyze the snapshot of a webpage (it contains canvas which is repainted) in some time intervals. To do so, I use `WKWebView.TakeSnapshot()` method where I set `AfterScreenUpdates` property of the `WKSnapshotConfiguration` to `true`. It basically works for me now, but I want to optimize it to only ask for the snapshot when the app really needs it.

Is there any delegate or method to override to know when the WKWebView's content changes or needs to be redrawn?

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to know if new content was loaded you first need to create a WKNavigationDelegate:

```
public class WKWebViewNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {

    }
}
```

And then assign it to the wk webview instance and you can get this call back in your delegate now:

```
var webView = new WKWebView(new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100), new WKWebViewConfiguration());
webView.NavigationDelegate = new WKWebViewNavigationDelegate();
```